# Laravel, Faker - Increment generated dateTime

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, increment, faker

I'm using Faker package in my Seeder to generate fake data for training events.

Each event has `starts_at` and `ends_at` fields. I want to populate the `ends_at` field with a `DateTime` that is after the one generated for `starts_at`, preferably by 1 to 8 hours, or even a fixed 1 hour difference would be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is an easy way to define the ends_at

```
$starts_at = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '+2 days', $endDate = '+1 week')->getTimeStamp()) ;

$ends_at= Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $starts_at)->addHours( $faker->numberBetween( 1, 8 ) );
```

Comment: Best way to transform \DateTime in \Carbon - 
https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/231

Answer (score 6):

Adapting the pattern described in [Build APIs You Won't Hate](https://leanpub.com/build-apis-you-wont-hate) and using the awesome [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) package, here's how you can do it:

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class UserEventsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {
        $faker = Faker::create();

        foreach (range(1, 15) as $index) {
            $startDate = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($faker->dateTimeBetween('-1 years', '+1 month')->getTimestamp());

            UserEvent::create([
                // ...

                'starts_at' => $startDate->toDateTimeString(),
                'ends_at'   => $startDate->addHours( $faker->numberBetween( 1, 8 ) )
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, Raphael_, when I run your code, I get this error: `DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`. Here is the full error log: http://laravel.io/bin/Jx34w And here is my entire seeder file: http://laravel.io/bin/QN9x4

Comment: This inserts `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the `starts_at` field. When I change `'starts_at' => $startDate->timestamp,` to `'starts_at' => $startDate,`, then the same date and time appear in both `starts_at` and `ends_at`. Here is my seeder now: http://laravel.io/bin/Mk5KO

Comment: I've made it work Raphael_. Thanks for your great help. Here is my code: http://laravel.io/bin/Yydmy. I will edit your code and accept your answer. Thanks again!