# How do you make unique dates while seeding database with fzaninotto/faker?

Tags: php, database, laravel-4

using https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

I am seeding my table with unique dates for the next thirty (30) days.

So I tried the following:

`'date' => $faker->unique()->dateTimeBetween($startDate = "now", $endDate = "30 days")->format('Y-m-d')`

But this yields redundant dates.

Comment: maybe this can help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700446/laravel-faker-increment-generated-datetime